# Laravel update query array to string conversion

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I'm processing batch jobs via a custom artisan command

I have a function that checks the job queue then attempts to update the job list

```
$batch_check = DB::table('jobs_has_batch_job_queue')
        ->where('jobs_job_id',$this->job_id[0]->job_id)
        ->get();

    if(count($batch_check) < 1)
    {
        var_dump($this->job_id[0]->job_id);die; 
        $this->info('Job Complete');
        DB::table('jobs')
            ->where('jobs_job_id',$this->job_id[0]->job_id)
            ->update(['status' => 'complete']);
    }
```

The `$batch_check` returns an empty array

and I see the

```
        $this->info('Job Complete');
```

echoed back in terminal and

```
$this->job_id[0]->job_id
```

returns back an integer, i get this value by running the following at the start of the batch process

```
        $this->job_id = DB::table('jobs')
            ->where('status','incomplete')
            ->limit(1)
            ->get();
```

all the docs say to pass an array to -> update

If anyone can spot where I'm going wrong it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

James Kirkby

First check that

$this->job_id[0]->job_id

give you any value or not if it give you a value then check that jobid is exist in database or not

```
 $exist = DB::table('jobs')
    ->where('jobs_job_id',$this->job_id[0]->job_id)->first();


dd(exist);
```

Comment: I know $this->job_id[0]->job_id has a value as i get the job_id as soon as i start the batch. (updated qs above with the code)

I'm then selecting the all the job items from the many to many table 'jobs_has_batch_job_queue' if there is none in there setting the status to complete so it doesnt select an empty job when running the batch function again